# XML DOM parsing br tag

Tags: html, xml, dom, parsing

I need to parse a xml string to obtain the xml DOM, the problem I'm facing is with the self closing html tag like `<br />` giving me the error of `Tag mismatch expected </br>`.

I'm aware this can be overcome by using `<br></br>` instead of `<br />` in the string, but is there a way this can be done without making the above change.

please help...

- Rob

Comment: what language are you parsing in?

Comment: Yes, how exactly are you parsing it? As others have said, that tag is perfectly fine. If you had a br tag without the self-closing slash, that would be different, and it would be an error.

Answer (score 1):

The self closing tag is entirely valid. I suspect you have a mismatched element elsewhere in your XML.

Answer (score 1):

```
Tag mismatch expected </br>
```

means you have forgotten to self-close the element. `<br/>` is just fine, but I think you've missed one or more HTML-style `<br>`s in your document. If you don't get a line number from your parser, you can always try loading the XML into a browser or validator to get a hint of where the problem is.